# Flask, React and Docker: Non-Zero Codes

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, flask

I am trying to follow the Flask/React tutorial [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-create-a-react--flask-project), on a plain Windows machine.

On Windows 10, without considering Docker, I have the tutorial working.

On Windows 10 under a docker system (ubuntu-based containers and docker-compose), I do not:

- The React server works under the docker.
- The Flask server won't successfully build.

The Dockerfile for the Flask server is:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository universe
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip yarn
RUN pip3 install flask
#RUN pip3 install venv

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app
#RUN python3 -m venv venv

RUN cd api/venv/Scripts 
RUN flask run --no-debugger
```

This fails at the very last line:

> The command '/bin/sh -c flask run --no-debugger' returned a non-zero code: 1

Note that I find myself in the unenviable position of trying to use/teach myself all of Docker, venv, react, and flask at the same time.  The `venv` commands are commented out because I'm not even sure venv makes sense in a docker (but what would I know?) and also because the `pip3 install venv` command halts with a `non-zero code:2`.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: You probably want `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` rather than `RUN flask ...`, and there are existing Flask containers, so I suggest using one of those, and no venv is not needed

Comment: @OneCricketeer advice about existing Flask containers is appreciated, but I've looked at those and-- due mostly to my very low level of understanding-- they don't make much sense to me.  Also because they're usually just Flask examples, not Flask/React examples.

Comment: Well, 1) You can look at the Dockerfile for them and see they are mostly like yours (without yarn). 2) Examples can be replaced with any code, that's kinda the point of Docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that flask can't find your app when you run your docker (especially as the docker build attempts to run it). If you want to use the docker only for the purpose of running your app through that docker, use `CMD` in the dockerfile, thus when running the docker image, it will start your flask app first thing.

Comment: That got the container built.  Container doesn't work, but that's a separate issue.  I'll mull this and the new error messages over, but I'm inclined to accept this answer once I've slept on it.

Comment: @Novak If you execute the command `flask run --no-debugger` on your own machine, does it work?

Comment: From a CMD terminal?  Yes.  If I fire up the React server from another CMD terminal, everything works satisfactorily.

Comment: You can try to play around with your container; `docker exec -it --rm [container-id] /bin/bash` and then check if something is missing or what exactly going on' amending your dockerfile correspondingly

Answer (score 2):

There are two obvious issues in the Dockerfile you show.

Each `RUN` command runs in a clean environment starting from the last known state of the image.  Settings like the current directory (and also environment variable values) are not preserved when a `RUN` command exits.  So `RUN cd ...` starts the `RUN` command from the old directory, changes to the new directory, and then doesn't remember that; the following `RUN` command starts again from the old directory.  You need the `WORKDIR` directive to actually change directories.

The `RUN` commands also run during the build phase.  They won't publish network ports or have access to databases; in a multi-container Compose setup they can't connect to other containers.  You probably want to run the Flask app as the main container `CMD`.

So you can update your Dockerfile to look like:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository universe
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip yarn

WORKDIR /app                         # Creates the directory as well

COPY requirements.txt ./             # Includes "flask"
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . ./

WORKDIR /app/api/venv/Scripts        # Not `RUN cd ...`
CMD flask run --no-debugger          # Not `RUN ...`
```

It is in fact common to just not use a virtual environment in Docker; the Docker image is isolated from any other Python installation and so it's safe to use the "system" Python package tree.  (I am a little suspicious of the `venv` directory in there, since virtual environments can't be transplanted into other setups very well.)

> Note that I find myself in the unenviable position of trying to use/teach myself all of Docker, venv, react, and flask at the same time.

Put Docker away for another day.  It's not necessary, especially during the development phase of your application.  If you read through SO questions there are a lot of questions trying to contort Docker into acting just like a local development environment, where it's really not designed for it.  There's nothing wrong with locally installing the tools you need to do your job, especially when they're very routine tools like Python and Node.